# Получение сообщений без динамического обновления

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

Как сделать получение сообщений без динамического обновления. Типа как в вк... То есть, чтобы как сообщение приходило в БД, оно сразу выдавалось на странице сайта.

Comment: БД должна быть обязательно MySQL?

Comment: Ну главное что вам нужно - это какая-то организация server-to-client мессаджинга. Вебсокеты или на худой конец лонг-поллинг

Comment: @MikhailVaysman ну стоит mysql и сайт полностью связан с mysql

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму сокеты доступны в flash. Поэтому решение базируется либо flash либо ajax

Comment: @СашаОсипов для подобной задачи подошел бы http://horizon.io/

Comment: @nick_n_a, что, флеш в 2016 (почти 2017) году, вы серьезно? Про сокеты, я имею в виду протокол websocket, который современными браузерами давно уже поддерживается. лонг-поллинг - это длинные опросы на основе ajax

Comment: Можно сделать на AngularJS

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ооо, я тащу этот ответ в javascript-faq)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму не уверен что это именно js-faq, потому что всё это нечто общее и реализация подразумевает клиент-сервер и значит абсолютно любой язык...но пусть висит, наверное